# angular html height is not 100% of window

Tags: angular, viewport

I downloaded the angular getting-started source code from https://angular.io/start and executed npm install and ng serve. All good so far.

Started tinkering the code to build my app. My app compiles and renders, but the height is limited to ~20% of the full window height. I have tried adding style in css everywhere but with no luck.

I have googled for a day and could not find links to point to my issue. Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you made`body` and`html` as height: 100% ?

Comment: please add some code and screenshot!

Comment: @DeepakJha - Yes, I had/tried html/body with height:100% and I think, I figured out/resolved the issue.
The home page/body initially loads with single blank div and the div gets populated with an iframe loading an external web-page. I realized, that when iframe loads into the div, the div does not auto-grow to full-page. instead iframe renders within the div's original/default height.
So, I had to add following css to the div container so that its occupies the full viewport even when its empty and when the iframe populates, it populates the full div.
height: calc(100vh - 76px);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding following CSS to the empty div in the home page that later gets populated with the `iframe` rendering external webpage.

```css
height: calc(100vh - 76px);
```